# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botbuilder.dialogs

Tags: python, botframework

I’m using open-source [bot-builder library](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python) and the [multi-turn-prompt example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/05.multi-turn-prompt).

It worked fine until 3 days ago when it stopped working.

When I run the bot code with VS code, it gives me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botbuilder.dialogs'.
```

When I install the requirements.txt it gives me:

```
Requirement already satisfied: botbuilder.dialogs>=4.8.0 in 
c:\users\---\botbuilder-samples\samples\python\05.multi-turn-prompt\botbuilder-python\libraries\botbuilder-dialogs 
(from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (4.15.0)
```

My operating system: Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise

Python version: 3.11.3

Comment: VSCode often uses its own installation of Python.  Are you installing it inside VSCode, or from your terminal?

Comment: I'm installing the packages in the vscode terminal in my project folder. Do I need to install it elsewhere? How come it recognizes the other packages but not the dialogs one?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to install and run outside VSCode? Are you using a venv?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the required packages as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python%2Cvs#python-templates) in your project. Then run the bot again. It should start correctly.